# Node.js how to iterate with async callback?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, iteration, asynccallback

What I am doing is using fs to stitch 5 pieces of html-page parts(`html, head, chead, topaside, main, footer`) together. The file name is `htmlpage.js`, so you can just run `node htmlpage.js file1 file2 file3 ...` in command line tool, and it will stitch those html-page parts together, then spit out `file1.html, file2.html, file3.html ...`. I don't like to use template engine/library/framework or whatever, especially when I am learning.
Here is the sorce code:

```
'use strict';
const fs = require('fs'),
      head = fs.createReadStream('./html-parts/head.html', 'utf8'),
      topaside = fs.createReadStream('./html-parts/topaside.html', 'utf8'),
      footer = fs.createReadStream('./html-parts/footer.html', 'utf8');

let name = process.argv.slice(2),
    htmlray = [],
    ni = 0,
    nl = name.length;
for (ni; ni < nl; ni ++) {
    let cheadP = './html-parts/' + name[ni] + '-head.html',
        mainP = './html-parts/' + name[ni] + '-main.html',
        htmlP = name[ni] + '.html',
        chead = fs.createReadStream(cheadP, 'utf8'),
        main = fs.createReadStream(mainP, 'utf8'),
        html = fs.createWriteStream(htmlP, 'utf8');
    //let those parts form an array
    htmlray = [html, head, chead, topaside, main, footer];
    openendPipe(htmlray[1], htmlray[0]);
    htmlray[1].on('end', () => {
        openendPipe(htmlray[2], htmlray[0]);
        htmlray[2].on('end', () => {
            openendPipe(htmlray[3], htmlray[0]);
            htmlray[3].on('end', () => {
                openendPipe(htmlray[4], htmlray[0]);
                htmlray[4].on('end', () => {
                    htmlray[5].pipe(htmlray[0]);
                    htmlray[5].on('end', () => {
                        console.log(name + '.html' + ' created');
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
}
function openendPipe(src, dst) {
    return src.pipe(dst, {end: false});
}
```

**But what if the `htmlray` has 100 parts, I want to be able to do an iteration to replace these code, let's call it `pipeblock`**:

```
openendPipe(htmlray[1], htmlray[0]);
    htmlray[1].on('end', () => {
        openendPipe(htmlray[2], htmlray[0]);
        htmlray[2].on('end', () => {
            openendPipe(htmlray[3], htmlray[0]);
            htmlray[3].on('end', () => {
                openendPipe(htmlray[4], htmlray[0]);
                htmlray[4].on('end', () => {
                    htmlray[5].pipe(htmlray[0]);
                    htmlray[5].on('end', () => {
                        console.log(name + '.html' + ' created');
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
```

I tried these solutions, they didn't work:
Solution 1:

```
(function () {
    let i = 0, count = 1;
    function nextpipe() {
        let arr = arguments[0];
        i ++;
        if (count > 5) return;
        openendPipe(arr[i], arr[0]);
        count ++;
        arr[i].on('end', nextpipe);
            }
    return nextpipe;
})();
//then replace 'pipeblock' with 'nextpipe(htmlray)';
//console.log: nextpipe is undefined.
```

Solution 2:

```
//replace 'pipeblock' with these code
let pi = 1,
    pl = htmlray.length - 1;
htmlray[pi].pipe(htmlray[0], {end: false});
htmlray[pi].on('end', nextpipe);
function nextpipe() {
    if (pi > pl) return console.log(name + '.html' + ' created');;
    pi ++;
    htmlray[pi].pipe(htmlray[0], {end: false});
    htmlray[pi].on('end', nextpipe);
}
//cosole.log: 
//htmlray[pi].pipe(htmlray[0], {end: false});
//TypeError: Cannot read property 'pipe' of undefined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I am reading through async and promise documentation, I get to the part about parallel, series and waterfall. My problem is about creating an html page, so it can't be done in parallel. But the documentation starts and talks a lot about parallel, and they just add confusion to my head. To grasp all of them is probably going to take a long time. Anyway, while I am experimenting, I come up with an easy solution of my own.
In my problem, the repetitive part is about check if previous html-part has done writing by using `readingStream.on('end', <do next writing>);`, so I make it into a function:

```
function ifend(src, src2, dst) {
    return src.on('end', () => {return openendPipe(src2, dst);});
}
```

Then I can turn `pipeblock` into:

```
openendPipe(htmlray[0], html);
ifend(htmlray[0], htmlray[1], html);
ifend(htmlray[1], htmlray[2], html);
ifend(htmlray[2], htmlray[3], html);
ifend(htmlray[3], htmlray[4], html);
```

Then I can do an iteration in a function:

```
function createHtml(src, dst) {
    let l = src.length - 1, 
        i = 0;
    openendPipe(src[0], dst);
    for (i; i < l; i ++) {
        //iterate ifend function.
        ifend(src[i], src[i + 1], dst);
    }
    return dst;
}
```

Now I can replace `pipeblock` with this:

```
createHtml(htmlray, html);
```

Answer (score 1):

This thing calls "callback hell" and you should use either some library to handle async calls like `async.js` or (better) use promises.

Just simply promisify `fs.readFile` like this (or write your own promise for `fs.createReadStream` it you want to use it)

```
const readFile = Promise.promisify(require('fs').readFile);
```

and then combine your request promises using `Promise.all()`

Here are examples `http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisify.html`, `http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.all.html` for `fs` for Bluebird promise library.

Comment: Yeah, I have watched couple of videos and read the documentation about promise and generator from time to time, but I dismissed them every time. Well,  if they are the only solution but not iteration, I guess I have to try them out. Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: I've lost plenty of time myself year or two ago trying to skip this stuff (and I really regret about this), and trying to experiment with callback loops, async waterfalls etc - promises are elegant and powerful solution. And already with error handling (this should be also important) - just add `.catch()` to you final promise.

Comment: Waite, I just remember that for my question of async callback 100 times, in promise, you still need to use then() for the next call 100 times. And in generator you still need to yield 100 times. Am I right? I don't really want to do that.

Comment: No, you have to create an array of the promises and then pass it to the `Promise.all()` or `Promise.join()` (I've opened my own code, I used `join`), so `Promise.join(...yourPromisesArray, (...arrayOfReplies) => { processReplies(arrayOfReplies) })`

Comment: Thanks, let me walk through your suggestion and read through documentation. I really need to understand things thoroughly. This is probably going to take the whole night. I will post final solution code when its done. See you later.